# Undefined name error in python socket module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to create a simple web server in python. I've imported the two modules I needed but I keep getting 'undefined name' error for AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM. I am fairy new  to this so any help would be appreciated.

```
from socket import socket
import sys 

serverPort = 6789
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: The only thing you imported from the `socket` module is the `socket` class, not any of the other things it defined.  You can (1) explicitly import `AF_INET`, etc; (2) do `from socket import *` (not recommended, since you can no longer tell where definitions are coming from; (3) `import socket`, and use `socket.socket`, `socket.AF_INET`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! The third option worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Having Context managers while dealing with Python sockets is safer and better approach, you can do it like that:

```
import socket
import sys 

serverHost = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 6789

## Context manager to allow you to allocate and release resources
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    ## Bind it to the specified IP and PORT
    s.bind((serverHost, serverPort))

    ## Listen on the server port to enable accepting connections
    s.listen()

    ## Then accept connections to the server
    conn, add = s.accept()
```